# How to pass data through a Link in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, e-commerce

I was trying to create an e-commerce app where I have a page with a list of products and on clicking on one of the products it goes into a separate product detail page. But I'm getting null data in the product details page.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "../Cards/Card";
import "./SustainabilityProducts.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function SustainabilityProducts() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const sustainabilityProductsData = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/products/category?productCategory=Sustainable Products`);
    setData(result.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    sustainabilityProductsData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="sustainabilityProducts">
      <div className="headingText">
        <div>
          <h3 className="heading">Sustainable Products</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="Description">
          <p classname='page-description' style={{ color: "#C9C9C9", paddingLeft: "5%" }}>
            Your finances and investments can also be green. We offer various
            financial products that are environmentally friendly.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h5 className="heading-secondary">Select a Type</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="cardsList">
        {data.map((card) => (
          <div className="cards" key={card.productId}>
            <Link to={{
              pathname: '/product-details', 
              state: { productTitle: card.productName }
            }}>
              <Card
                img={card.imageUrl}
                title={card.productName}
                desc={card.productDescription}
              />
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SustainabilityProducts;
```

```
import React from 'react'
import car from '../../Images/car.png';
import leaf from "../../Images/leaf.jpg";
import './ProductDetails.css';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProductDetails() {

  const location = useLocation();
  console.log('Location State:', location.state);
  const productTitle = location.state && location.state.productTitle;

  console.log('Product Title:', productTitle);


  return (
    <div className='basic'>
      <img style={{ width: "100%" }} src={car} alt="car"></img>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div className='basic1'>
        <h1>{productTitle}</h1>
        <img src={leaf} alt="leaf"></img>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h4>
          APR: 5.29%
          <br />
          Term: 60 months
          <br />
          Loan amount: Up to $120,000
          <br />
          Interest rate: 2.79%
        </h4>
        <br />
        <ul className='basic2'>
          <li>Driving an electric vehicle means you would be contributing to environmental sustainability since electric vehicles release fewer harmful carbon dioxide emissions.</li>
          <br /><li>The costs of owning an EV are typically less than a gasoline-powered vehicle.</li>
          <br /> <li>Savings may include a lower cost to charge your electric vehicle (when compared fuel costs) as well as savings on maintenance costs, since EVS typically need less maintenance.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginLeft: "-78px" }}><button className='basic3' >Apply Now </button></div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductDetails
```

These are the two pages. I'm trying to load the product name for now from the API data.